# python f.read() and f.seek() is slow when reading data over server

Tags: python, binary, seek

I have a function that reads binary data on files stored on a remote server. It is extremely slow first time I run it on a given file, and sufficiently fast next time I read the same file.

This is a mystery to me, since the file is both opened and closed in a child function (and thus performance should be consistent and not depend on whether I have read that specific file previously).

The data is stored in binary files of ~300mb, and I need to read every N numbers. E.g. I may read the 1st number, the 11th number, the 21st number and so on until end of file. This may be described as the file containing a ncol x nrow matrix, where the first set of ncol numbers is row 1, second set of ncol numbers is row 2 etc. I want to read a column, i.e. one number per row.

I use f.seek() to set the file pointer to the correct position in the file.

Below code uses ~10s first time running, and 0.2s subsequent times. Note that this time is only reading the data, opening the file is fast. Why does the performance change when I open and close the file between each time?

def ReadBinaryFile(filename,col,ncol):

```
"""
Args: 
    filename: binary file with float numbers (4-byte) stored in columns
    col: column to read
    ncol: number of columns in file (needed to separate data)

Description:
    -reads 4-byte numeric data from specified column and converts to float

Returns: 
    X: list with numeric data

"""
#--------hard-coded variables:
numBytes=4 #4-byte numbers

#---------open file

f = open(filename,'rb') #open file
f.seek(0,2) #put pointer to end of file
nmax = f.tell()/numBytes #total length of data
nrow = nmax/ncol #number of rows 

X = [0]*nrow #allocate memory
t0 = time.time()  #start timer  

for i in xrange(nrow):

    f.seek((col-1+i*ncol)*numBytes)
    bindata = f.read(numBytes)

    X[i] = float(struct.unpack('f',bindata)[0])

t1 = time.time() #end timer
print('Elapsed time reading binary data: ' + str(t1-t0))    

f.close()

return X
```

Update:
I rewrote the loop and replaced f.seek() with f.read() to move forward in the file.

```
  f.seek((col-1+i*ncol)*numBytes) #set initial file pointer
  for i in xrange(nrow):


    bindata = f.read(numBytes) #read desired data

    X[i] = float(struct.unpack('f',bindata)[0]) 
    f.read(numBytes*(ncol-1)) #move to next row by reading data.
```

Original code, reading same file twice with f.seek() to move file pointer: 
First time reading file=10.2s, consecutive read=0.16s.

Updated code, reading same file twice with f.read() to move file pointer:
First time reading file=1.67s, consecutive read=0.25s.

So updated code is 5x times faster 1st time reading the file, but 2x slower next time. I restarted kernel between each test, and did the test several times to verify results.

This is frustrating. I am looking for ways to speed up the code. All ideas are appreciated!

Comment: There are at least three reasons it could be faster to read the same file a second time: (1) all or most of the contents cached in your OS’s file cache, your filesystem plugin’s cache, etc.; (2) reuses an existing connection so it can skip some expensive setup; (3) cached on the remote server’s file cache so you still have to pay the network costs but not the cost of reading the data from a disk. Closing and reopening a file probably wouldn’t affect #3, but could easily affect the other two.

Comment: This makes sense, and the logical solution is thus to rewrite the order I loop over data.